# If Statement Scala behaving Strangely

Tags: scala

if statment in scala is behaving strangely

```
scala> val a = 10
a: Int = 10

scala> if (a > 10) 1
res10: AnyVal = ()

scala> if (a <= 10) 1
res12: AnyVal = 1
```

Why didn't we get return type as Int? Why we got AnyVal

Comment: What did you expect to happen in the first `if`?

Answer (score 6):

> if statment in scala is behaving strangely

Scala doesn't have an `if` *statement*. In fact, Scala has no statements *at all*. Scala has an `if` *expression*, or more precisely, a [*conditional expression*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

In fact, *if* Scala *had* an `if` statement, then your question wouldn't make sense, because statements have no value and thus no type.

> Why didn't we get return type as Int? Why we got AnyVal

As the documentation says:

> The conditional expression `if` `(`*e<sub>1</sub>*`)` *e<sub>2</sub>* `else` *e<sub>3</sub>* chooses one of the values of *e<sub>2</sub>* and *e<sub>3</sub>*, depending on the value of *e<sub>1</sub>*. […] The type of the conditional expression is the [weak least upper bound](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#weak-conformance) of the types of *e<sub>2</sub>* and *e<sub>3</sub>*.

This makes sense: the conditional can be either true or false, so the value of the conditional expression is either the "then" part or the `else` part. Since the value can be either the "then" part or the `else` part, the type of the expression *obviously* must be compatible with both.

In your case, the value of the "then" part is `1` whose type is [`Int`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) and the value of the `else` part is `()` whose type is [`Unit`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html):

> A short form of the conditional expression eliminates the else-part. The conditional expression `if` `(`*e<sub>1</sub>*`)` *e<sub>2</sub>* is evaluated as if it was `if` `(`*e<sub>1</sub>*`)` *e<sub>2</sub>* `else` `()`.

Therefore, whatever the type of the *whole* expression is, it must be compatible with both `Int` and `Unit`. And the most-precise possible type that is compatible with both `Int` and `Unit` is [`AnyVal`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyVal.html):[image: Scala Class Hierarchy showing the Root Classes and Value Classes, including AnyVal, Unit, and Int][Source: [Scala 2.13 Language Specification – Section 12 *The Scala Standard Library*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#value-classes)]

As you can see in the left half of the tree, the weak-LUB of `Int` and `Unit` is obviously `AnyVal`.

Comment: What a long way to say "you need an `else`" :D

Comment: "Scala has no statements at all."... well, this assertion is not very accurate. At least according to the Scala Spec -> https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#statements